# Passing variable between view and JS; Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am first passing a JS variable 'confirmed' to my Django view via POST request.
I then run a python script which takes this variable and does some processing.
Finally I want to pass it back to my html/JS so I can display the processed data.

I am currently trying to use Django sessions to achieve my goal but there is a '1 session delay', so the session variable which I update is returning as the value from the previous session.

Is there a better way I can pass the variable from my view to JS/a fix for my current solution?

VIEW:

```
def crossword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Session.objects.all().delete()

        str_squares = (request.body).decode('utf-8')
        squares = [int(i) for i in str_squares.split(',')]

        letters = puzzle_solver.solve_puzzle(3, squares)
        # print(letters)
        for each_square in letters.keys():
            request.session[each_square] = letters[each_square]

        request.session.modified = True

    return render(request, 'crossword.html')
```

JS:

```
            // Output a list of active squares
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var generate = { Generate:function(){ 
                var confirmed = [];
                for (i=0; i<active_boxes.length; i++){
                    confirmed.push(active_boxes[ i ].id_num);
                }
                console.log(confirmed);

                xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                xhr.send(c=confirmed);

                console.log("{{ request.session.keys }}")
                console.log("{{ request.session.values }}")
                var tester = parse_session_keys("{{ request.session.keys }}");

                console.log(tester);
                solve_crossword(tester);
             }};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are not sending the response directly back to JS? In your `views.py`, you can do

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def crossword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        str_squares = (request.body).decode('utf-8')
        squares = [int(i) for i in str_squares.split(',')]
        letters = puzzle_solver.solve_puzzle(3, squares)

        return JsonResponse(letters)

    return render(request, 'crossword.html')
```

After sending your request, wait and read the response directly as JSON then play with it in your JS code, as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest).

If there is any reason preventing you from doing this (for example there might be a form also makes POST requests to the same page thus you need to eventually land on rendering the crossword template), allocate another url for your api like `/api/crossword`

Your original idea of using session should not be used in this use case, especially with your `Session.objects.all().delete()` line (don't delete all session data without checking).